# Vue.js Component loss state after event was triggerd

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following problem. In my vue-component i triggerd a event when a item was added or removed from a list.

```
  export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
  @Prop() private idCount: number = 0;
  @Prop() private toDos: ToDo[] = new Array<ToDo>();
  @Prop() private toDoText: ToDoText = new ToDoText();

  public NewToDo() {
    let element = document.getElementById("NewToDoName") as HTMLInputElement;
    let name = element.value;
    element.value = "";

    var toDo = new ToDo();
    toDo.name = name;
    toDo.id = ++this.idCount;

    this.toDos.push(toDo);
    this.$emit('scrollChange');
  }

  public DeleteToDo(index: number) {
    this.toDos.splice(index, 1);
    this.$emit('scrollChange');
  }
}
```

So in my parent component i react to this event

```
<HelloWorld msg="Welcome to your ToDo-App" v-on:scrollChange="onChanged()" class="jumbotron"/>
```

And this is my method

```
    onChanged(){
    this.canScroll = true;
    return true; 
  }
```

The property `canScroll` is binded to another child component

```
<NavBarBottom v-bind:canScroll="canScroll"/>
```

Where I have this logic

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" v-bind:class="[!isFixed ? 'fixed-bottom' : 'bottom']">

export default class NavBarBottom extends Vue {

@Prop() public canScroll : Boolean = false;
@Prop() public isFixed : Boolean = false;

@Watch('canScroll')
onChange(){
    //this.isFixed = this.hasVerticalScroll(undefined);
    console.log(this.isFixed);
}

private hasVerticalScroll(node : any){
    //some checks
}
}
```

So if i fire the event for the firsttime everything is fine.

[image: Component_Fine]

But when I add again a Item to my array in the `HelloWorld-Component` nothing happend. When I look in the debugger the component state is delete like this:

[image: Component]

Can someone explain me why this happends?

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the usage of [@Prop (vue-property-decorator)](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#propoptions-propoptions--constructor--constructor---decorator) I believe that the way that the prop is set could be causing this issue. Please try to use `default: x` instead of defining the initial value. 
So your code would looks like:

```
@Prop() private msg!: string;
@Prop({ default: 0 }) private idCount: number;
@Prop({ default: new Array<ToDo>() }) private toDos: ToDo[];
@Prop({ default: new ToDoText() }) private toDoText: ToDoText;
```